# How to use regular expression for fetching specific data?

Tags: java, regex

I have input stream with the following data:

```
---------------------------------------------
manil@manil-ubvm:~$ db2level
DB21085I  Instance "manil" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10010" with 
level identifier "0201010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120403", "LINUXAMD64101", and Fix 
Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/home/manil/sqllib".
---------------------------------------------
```

From above i need `v10.1.0.0` to be stored in a string variable.

How to do that using java regular expression?

Comment: We need more rules: the string `v10.1.0.0` can be reach in many ways. Will it whatever be preceded by `DB2`, and contained between double quotes? Will it always be the same format (i.e. `v` + 4 numbers separated by dots)? Have you already tried something?

Comment: Yes, it will always be the same format.

Comment: What about my other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this to capture the version pattern :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

    public class RTest {

            public static void main(String [] args) {
                    String raw_data = "asdkgjasdbf984 sdkjfashfiu 4qwsadkfjnv w98sa-asdf08gywbfsd v1231.123.12.11.1 fkjsdfn9823isd";
                    Pattern version_find = Pattern.compile("v[\\d+\\.?]+");
                    Pattern directory_find = Pattern.compile("[\\/[^\\/]+]+");
                    Matcher version_finder = version_find.matcher(raw_data);
                    while(version_finder.find()) {
                          System.out.println(version_finder.group());
                    }
            }
    }
```

Output is :

```
v1231.123.12.11.1
/isd/asdasd2903 ajshdaq09r34/adsj 38/
```

You **really** need to understand regexes deeply if you are a programmer. They are one of the essentials. They are hard at first, but once you 'crack them' you don't forget it. Like riding a bike.

Comment: If i want to find "/home/manil/sqllib" frm the same input stream, wht will be the regular expression to compile?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that, too. But see the **emphasis**

Answer (score 1):

This will suit your needs:

```
String version = yourLine.replaceAll(".*(v\\d+([.]\\d+){3}).*", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need regularExpression here

just use

`String .contain()` method and `String substring()`

Comment: I don't know what exact value will come after "v". I am able to reach line number four i.e. "Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120403", "LINUXAMD64101", and Fix". But I need whatever number comes after v, like vxx.x.x.x

Comment: you can search for DB2 using contain() and after that you can substring() using v as starting till the \"

Comment: DB2 is not fixed, it can change. but format (i.e. v + 4 numbers separated by dots will be same.